# How to export morph targets from Blender to three.js?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I am trying to export morph targets from a Blender file to three.js. My objective is to have a json file with an array "morphTargets" inside. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Three.js comes with a [Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/exporter/geometry.py).

Simply copy the **io_mesh_threejs** folder (from three.js/utils/exporters/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs) to the **scripts/addons** folder in Blender (e.g. /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.73/scripts/addons on OSX (remember you need to right-click blender.app and select Show Packages Content))

Once you've done that, restart Blender, and enable the exporter from the Preferences Panel (in the Add-ons tab):
[image: three.js Blender exporter enable]

This will add an extra option menu option: **File > Export > Three.js(.json)**

With your morph animated mesh selected, use this option, and make sure you enable the **Morph animation** option in the Animation section of the Exporter options:

[image: Three.js exporter options: morph animation]

This should generate the .json file you're after with "morphTargets".

Comment: BTW that inside-blender.app dir doesn't work with current versions anymore, what works is to put into the user's library -- we updated the Mac instructions there to say that recently: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender .. AFAIK must and should use /Users/(myuser)/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.7X/scripts/addons

Comment: I didn't know that. I took the screenshots above as I installed the addon (using the blender.app dir) but on Blender 2.73. I haven't tested with 2.75 yet. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have figured this out. I created one keyframe for each morph target and limited the timeline to just the keyframes created. And then on the exporting configuration, I have selected morph animation.